# Requiring a single React child component in TypeScript (TSX)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript1.8, tsx

If I have an interface that overrides and specifies a single child, something like:

```
interface Props extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement> {
    children?: React.ReactElement<any>;
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    // ...
}
```

IntelliSense correctly shows the single element child prop type, but I can use a component with these props with multiple child components without any errors:

```
<MyComponent>
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>world</div>
</MyComponent>
```

This compiles fine with TypeScript 1.8.30.0, but at run time it breaks:

```
Invariant Violation: ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element.
```

It does work with only one `<div/>` child element, since the component code is written for that scenario. This seems like a bug to me--I expected it to realize that two `<div/>` elements doesn't match the definition of `children`. I figured I would ask here first, though, before opening an issue, in case I'm missing something.

Is it possible to require only a single child via `this.props.children`, or must I add a specific prop?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
export const Example = (props: { children: ReactElement }) => {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can find the relevant information below.

[Single Child](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#single-child)

To quote:

> With React.PropTypes.element you can specify that only a single child can be passed to a component as children.

It is possible to enforce only one child.

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    children: React.PropTypes.element.isRequired
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children} // This must be exactly one element or it will warn.
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: This may work for JSX, but I am trying to get a TypeScript compiler error from TSX. Does specifying propTypes also indicate to TS that it shouldn't allow multiple children? I've never seen propTypes change anything in TSX before...

Comment: Unfortunately TSX isn't that smart .. yet. Just imagine a scenario where you would call a function that would return some content, which would end up as children in `MyComponent`. TSX would not be able to tell ... yet. :) Might be worth a shot to file that ticket, but it'll be a long one.

Comment: Right but TS knows the return type of the function and the type of the children prop, so it should be able to compare them and see that they don't match up.